# Wildcards in bash

Tags: bash, wildcard

Suppose I have two folders (stored in my home directory) `dir1` and `dir2` both which contain a file with the same name, say `hello_world.txt`. The contents of each `hello_world.txt` file is **different**, however.

I can do

```
ls dir*/hello_world.txt
dir1/hello_world.txt  dir2/hello_world.txt
```

which would list the two files. That's great! But...

**how can I make a copy of the two files**, using the `*` wild card, ***and* re-naming them uniquely at the same time.** I.e. I want the output to be

```
hello_world1.txt hello_world2.txt
```

and for that to be in my home directory.

Comment: You can use a `for` loop.

Comment: @user4098326 I could but that involves having to actually write more than one line. Is there not a simpler way?

Comment: One line doesn't always mean simpler.  Shorter isn't always better.

Comment: You could write the `for` loop all on one line but that won't change the amount of logic you need to write to do it. But no, you can't get simpler because you need a certain amount of logic to get the output format you want. If you don't care about the output format directly then `mv --backup=numbered dir*/hello_world.txt output/` might be enough for you.

Comment: It's a shame something like this doesn't work: `cp dir*/hello_world.txt hello_world*` where the `*` in the first part is used in the second part

Comment: @AntoniusGavin that's normally not what you want from `*`. `*` should be considered as expansion, and nothing more. and even if you use a for loop, you can still squeeze it into one line.

Comment: Fair enough. I accept your comments and will use a for loop. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A for loop really is the best solution here: It's clear, maintainable, and despite being multiline, very simple:

```
i=0
for hw in dir*/hello_world.txt; do
    dest="$HOME/${hw##*/}"
    cp "$hw" "${dest%.*}$((++i)).txt"
done
```

Inputs:

```
$ tree
.
├── dir1
│   └── hello_world.txt
└── dir2
    └── hello_world.txt
```

Outputs:

```
$ tree
.
├── dir1
│   ├── hello_world.txt
└── dir2
    └── hello_world.txt
$ (cd ~ && tree)
.
├── hello_world1.txt
└── hello_world2.txt
```

Comment: So close!  OP also requested that the copied files be placed in their home directory.  Maybe throw in a `basename`?

Answer (score 0):

GNU Coreutils has an option `-b` to `cp` which allows you to avoid overwriting files.

```
cp -b numbered dir*/hello_world.txt $HOME
```

However, this doesn't give full control over the generated names.

For detailed documentation, see [info coreutils `cp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html) and [Backup options](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Backup-options.html) in the Coreutils documentation.